# При запуске по startx, графического интерфейса вот такое выдает и не запускает:

Tags: ubuntu

При запуске по startx, графического интерфейса вот такое выдает и не запускает: 
    hostname: Name or service not known 
    xauth: (stdin):1: bad display name "vz1018510:0" in "add" command

```
 X.Org X Server 1.11.3 
 Release Date: 2011-12-16 
 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0 
 Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 
 Current Operating System: Linux vz1018510 2.6.32-5-openvz-amd64 #1 SMP Sun     Sep 23 11:32:18 UTC 2012 x86_64 
 Kernel command line: quiet 
 Build Date: 12 February 2015 02:49:01PM 
 xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see 
 Current version of pixman: 0.30.2 
 Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org 
 to make sure that you have the latest version. 
 Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting, 
 (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational, 
 (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. 
 (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Dec 10 01:47:54 2016 
 (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d" 

 Fatal server error: 
 xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory) 


 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org 
 for help. 
 Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional      information. 

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log 
 Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file. 
 xinit: giving up 
 xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory 
 xinit: server error 
 xauth: (argv):1: bad display name "vz1018510:0" in "remove" command
```

Вот, что в Xorg:

```
 [ 53314.745] 
 Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at  
 for help. 
 [ 53314.745] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for      additional information. 
 [ 53314.745] 
 [ 53314.745] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: KDSETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor 
 [ 53314.745] (WW) xf86CloseConsole: VT_GETMODE failed: Bad file descriptor 
 [ 53314.745] ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log 
 [ 53314.745] Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Comment: Так же по комманже проверки видео карты выдает вот такое:                    ~# lspci -nn | grep VGA
     pcilib: Cannot open /proc/bus/pci
     lspci: Cannot find any working access method. И папка bus реально нет в системе.

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal server error:
>    xf86OpenConsole: Cannot open /dev/tty0 (No such file or directory)

требуется изменение параметров вашей виртуальной машины. точнее, [изменение прав доступа к файлу `/dev/tty0`](https://forum.openvz.org/index.php?t=msg&th=776&goto=4119&S=cf729d0b6e8f6c73f68e07dc45256979#msg_4119).

```
host# vzctl set VEID --devnodes /dev/tty0:rw --save
```

Comment: Добавил права chmod 777. Сейчас вот такое пишет:                                       hostname: Name or service not known
     xauth: (stdin):1:  bad display name "vz1018510:0" in "add" command

     X: /tmp/.X11-unix has suspicious mode (not 1777) or is not a directory,       aborting.
     xinit: giving up
     xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
     xinit: server error
     xauth: (argv):1:  bad display name "vz1018510:0" in "remove" command

Comment: host# vzctl set VEID --devnodes /dev/tty0:rw --save - и да эта, комманда не работает у меня. Пишет что, -bash: host#: command not found.

Comment: И еще у меня все папки файлы, ну там dev,etc,var и т п не в корне диска, а в папке /. Бывает, но редко, в корень возвращаются.

Comment: *Пишет что, -bash: host#: command not found* — естественно, изменение параметров виртуальной машины можно произвести только извне её, в реальной системе. если не вы владелец сервера, то обратитесь к владельцу.

Comment: Не понял, это вы про что?

Comment: вы используете виртуальную машину (контейнер) openvz. изменить её параметры можно «снаружи», из «хост-системы».

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду не посредственно ввести с клавиатуры данного сервера?

Comment: можно и удалённо, но подключившись к «хост-системе», а не к виртуальной машине.

Comment: У меня виртуальный арендованный сервер, доступа к host машине нету.

Comment: @ПетровСидор, тогда вам надо обратиться с проблемой к арендодателю.